# Why could Android Studio and gradle be using different classpaths for unit tests?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, classpath

I have a suite of unit tests that run fine when run via `./gradlew :project:testDebugUnitTests`. However, when I run them in Android Studio, I get an obscure issue that I eventually traced to what seems to be Android Studio using a different classpath from this Gradle command.

The dependency in question is Byte Buddy and I'm running into a variant of [this bug](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1520) which was fixed in 1.9.0. Running `./gradlew dependencies` indicates that 1.9.10 will be used in my build, but when I look at the command line that Android Studio is using to run my tests, the `-classpath` argument includes **both** 1.8.10 **and** 1.9.10, and the 1.8.10 version is first in the list.

I'm really puzzled by what could be causing this, since I would have expected that Android Studio would get the classpath from its Gradle integration. I'd love any leads for why this could be happening or how to debug further.

Comment: So $JAVA_HOME points to 1.9.0 in your environment? Are you running Android Studio 4?

Comment: Gradle's $JAVA_HOME points to the Android Studio bundled JDK, which is 1.8.0. Not sure why you guessed 1.9 but is it possible you mistook the Byte Buddy versions for the JDK versions?

Comment: And I've reproduced the issue on both Android Studio 3.5 and 4.

Comment: Does your Gradle file have any references to ByteBuddy 1.8.10, at all?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the project, as dumb as  it sounds?

Comment: As a quick fix have you considered tracking down which dependency introduces `1.8.10` version using `./gradlew :app:dependencies` and then excluding Byte Buddy version 1.8.10 from that artifact?

Comment: @Taschi There are no references to bytebuddy of any version; it's only a transitive dependency. Refreshing didn't work.